# When will the Wayland server ping a client?

Tags: linux, wayland

When will the Wayland server ping a client to check if it is receiving events?

Answer (score 1):

The Wayland server is allowed to ping whenever it wants so this is implementation-dependent. Most probably it will do so any time it considers the client should acknowledge an event.